# Modelling multiple tables in Sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, model

I am about to create a database with four tables , A table with Games Played a table with Players, a table with their statistics and a table of statistics codes, which will have a relationship with each other. Do I have to model and the four of them in Android Studio, or just model players and games?

Comment: ...what do packages have to do with this?

Comment: main package will be com.games.blabla and the models will be in com.games.blabla.model

Comment: You can put everything into a single package if you want to. There are no restrictions whatsoever

Comment: yes ok with that but what about models , each table should have and its model? e.g players , game, statistics and codes?

Comment: Create 1, 10 or 100 packages. It is up to you. What is your question? How to organize your packages? There is no answer. However you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

In a single package is possible. I'm currently working on an App that has 8 tables at present. I think you could even have multiple databases in single package. I haven't tried though.